# Universal Windows App - Storing and Updating Data for multiple users

Tags: c#, sql, win-universal-app

I would like to be able to record some information about a specific user locally within my Universal Windows App, How would I go about doing this in such a way I can query the data after a period of time and pull back results? I have seen that this is possible using SQLite, is there any other technologies that could achieve this.

I would then also like to store some generic data such as click information on a database which would be updated by all users of the application.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I think SQLite would be a great way to do it. However, if the data is simple enough, you can just store them using files. Use `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder` to access files specific for the user (or `RoamingFolder`, if you want this data to automatically roam between devices), and `ApplicationData.Current.SharedLocalFolder` to store data for all users on the device.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going for things like click information,navigation and other usage data, I strongly suggest that you look into Application Insights. This is a very simple library that you more or less can just right-click to add to your project in Visual Studio. It will give you all sorts of telemetry right out of the box for your UWP apps, WebApps, and even Android/iOS apps. Think of it as the UWP version of Google Analytics, only so much better :)

You generally do nearly nothing other than to just configure it with an ID, but if you want to, you can track all sorts of custom events, and not worry about how to store them. Internally, Application Insights will send telemetry to Azure when it can. When it can't, it doesen't. 
Here's the getting started page:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/application-insights/

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/transitioning-mobile-apps-from-application-insights-to-hockeyapp/